# How to disable black outline in Chrome

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

This issue is present only in Chrome, the map canvas displays a black outline when clicked (on focus). This is supposedly some kind of accessibility feature turned on by default since Chrome 83. I tried disabling this with css overrides but no success:

```
  *:focus, *:focus-visible, *:focus-within {
    outline: none !important;
  }
```

When unfocused:

[image: Unfocused]

When focused:

[image]

How to remove this, it really ruins the look of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be sufficient for me:

```
* {
    outline: none;
}
```

or, to minimise impact on accessibility:

```
.mapboxgl-canvas {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, correct answer. I know why it didn't work for me. I was adding the style into a scoped Vue component style section, duh.